# Vector function tough question

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-analysis

If a curve has the property that the position vector $\vec{r}(t)$ is always perpendicular to the tangent vector $\vec{r'}(t)$, how can I show that the curve lies on a sphere with center the origin?

This is a problem from J. Stewart's book, but I'm stuck, so any tip will be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remember that $|v|^2=\langle v,v\rangle$, this with the camareon's answer solve you problem (You have to derivate your function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}\,'(t) = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}(\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}(t))$.